# ImportError: cannot import name 'init' from 'pushover' (/usr/src/app/src/python-pushover/pushover/__init__.py)

Tags: python, docker, pushover

I'm running [this container](https://github.com/volschin/docker-events-pushover) (it was forked from code that I cobbled together before, but has been enhanced since then).

It used to work, but after recent changes it now fails with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/app/app.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pushover import init, Client
ImportError: cannot import name 'init' from 'pushover' (/usr/src/app/src/python-pushover/pushover/__init__.py)
```

Looks like this docker image is pulling in https://github.com/almir1904/python-pushover/

Any ideas how to go about debugging and fixing this?

I was going to reach out to https://github.com/volschin, but there are no contact details so I cannot.

Examining the docker image file, I can see the folder `/usr/src/app/src/python-pushover/pushover` exists, and `__init__.py` is in there.

I tried removing and re-pulling the container down.

Comment: `__init__.py` is not directly imported, it is what is imported when you import a package and becomes the namespace of the package. e.g. `var1` in `a/__init__.py` becomes `a.var1`.

Comment: I get that, but I don't get how I go about fixing this?

I can build the image from the Dockerfile, but when I run it I just get the error about not being able to import init...